# PhpStorm not refreshing Structure tool window

Tags: php, phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm 8.

When I update some PHPDoc comments, the Structure tool window doesn't get updated.

How can I solve this problem?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Switch to another tab and back? In any case: why do you need to see it updated straight away? I'm not saying that it should not do that, but why it's so important? It's just a structure and it is virtual entry (as done via PHPDoc tag)..

Comment: @LazyOne, autocompletion?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the same thing recently, there seems to be a bug in the latest release. Try `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart…` – this should do the trick.

In the meanwhile I've reported the issue [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-25252). Vote up and provide any additional details, that will help to get it resolved quicker.

Comment: Such local parsing issue (that happens after you update PHPDoc) should not really be resolved by invalidating caches (that is for more "serious" cases). Have you tried `Code | Inspect Code...` and run it on current file? But in any case: it is undesired behaviour and should be treated as bug.